# How to extract document id from response - ElasticSearch Java Low Level Rest Client

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm indexing document without id into ElasticSearch using the following code:

```
Response response = restClient.performRequest(
            HttpPost.METHOD_NAME,
            "/posts/doc/",
            Collections.emptyMap(),
            entity);
```

I want to extract the document id that was generated by ElasticSearch from the response. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the response object for that `response.getEntity().getContent()`.

If you are using Jackson, you can then deserialize the stream as a Map `mapper.readValue(response.getEntity().getContent(), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});`

Then from the map, read the `_id` field.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

response.getEntity().getContent() is **InputStream object**.

So, you could you BufferedReader also.

Try this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    out.append(line);
}
System.out.println(out.toString());
```